# Kotlin android compile error about service

Tags: android, kotlin

When I try to write a service with Kotlin

```java
package com.personal.distribute.service

import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder

class MyService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return null
    }
}
```

I got some compile errors like that

> e: F:\FastAppStory\android\quickappsdk\src\main\java\com\psersonal\distribute\service\MyService.kt: (7, 1): Class 'MyService' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun getBasePackageName(): String! defined in android.app.Service

I did not find the corresponding possible problem.

Comment: gradle build version is 4.0.1. gradle is 6.3.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error is that a local library to CompileOnly overwrites the Context...  Cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

> The cause of this error is that a local library to `CompileOnly` overwrites the `Context`... Cause the problem

That means you will need to review your project's [`build.gradle` file(s)](https://developer.android.com/build) (project-level `build.gradle`, and one for each module, module-level `build.gradle`). The dependencies causing issues are likely declared in a module-level `build.gradle` file, particularly the one associated with your app module.

Within the `dependencies` block, identify any lines that start with [`compileOnly`](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies). These are the dependencies that are included for compilation but are not packaged into the final APK:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.example:some-library:1.0'
    compileOnly 'another.example:another-library:2.0'
    // Other dependencies
}
```

Each of these has the potential to be the source of the conflict, especially if they define or extend Android SDK classes like `Context`.

You could try and automate the inspection process with a script looking for a `MyService` class in the `compileOnly` dependencies. The actual class files are not included in your project directory but are referenced from your project's dependencies, typically downloaded to your Gradle cache.

```kotlin
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

fun main() {
    val projectRootPath = "path/to/your/project-root" 
    val gradleFiles = findGradleFiles(projectRootPath)
    gradleFiles.forEach { file ->
        println("Inspecting: ${file.absolutePath}")
        inspectFileForCompileOnlyDependencies(file)
    }
}

fun findGradleFiles(rootPath: String): List<File> {
    val start = Paths.get(rootPath)
    return Files.walk(start)
        .filter { path -> path.toString().endsWith("build.gradle") || path.toString().endsWith("build.gradle.kts") }
        .map { it.toFile() }
        .toList()
}

fun inspectFileForCompileOnlyDependencies(file: File) {
    val compileOnlyDependencies = file.readLines().filter { it.trim().startsWith("compileOnly") }
    if (compileOnlyDependencies.isNotEmpty()) {
        println("Found compileOnly dependencies in ${file.name}:")
        compileOnlyDependencies.forEach { dependency ->
            println(dependency)
            // Additional step: Suggesting next steps for each dependency
            suggestInvestigationSteps(dependency)
        }
    } else {
        println("No compileOnly dependencies found in ${file.name}.")
    }
    println()
}

fun suggestInvestigationSteps(dependency: String) {
    // Extracting the dependency group and name for better clarity
    val dependencyParts = dependency.removePrefix("compileOnly").trim().removeSurrounding("\"").split(":")
    if (dependencyParts.size >= 2) {
        val (group, name) = dependencyParts.take(2)
        println("-> Investigate: $group:$name")
        println("   Check if this library contains a 'MyService' class or overrides Android 'Context'.")
        println("   Consider checking the library's source code if available, or its documentation for more details.")
        println("   Repository search or browsing might be necessary.")
    }
}
```

For each dependency identified by the script, you will need to investigate further manually. That means checking the library's documentation or source code (if available) for any classes named `MyService` or modifications to the `Context` class.